# Python in Visual Studio Code getting winError[5] Access denied from idescripts

Tags: python-3.x, windows, powershell, visual-studio-code

it is my first time posting here so I apologize if this question is not correctly formatted. 
I installed VSC to use it in developing STM32 code. I found the damongranlabs idescripts in github that would help greatly. While running the update.py script, I get the winError[5] access denied. VSC is using powershell as a terminal and I am running windows 10 with Python 3.8 32bit.

I have tried running VSC as an admin with no luck.

The following is what I get in powershell after attempting to run the script:

```
Windows PowerShell
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

Try the new cross-platform PowerShell https://aka.ms/pscore6

PS D:\Development\STM32\cubemxprojects\476EncTest> &  d:/Development/STM32/cubemxprojects/476EncTest/ideScripts/update.py
Update started.

Existing '.vscode' folder used.
One STM32CubeMX file found: 476EncTest.ioc
Existing 'Makefile' file found (restored from '.backup').
Copy of file (new name: Makefile): D:/Development/STM32/cubemxprojects/476EncTest/Makefile.backup
Makefile 'print-variable' function added.
Valid 'buildData.json' file found.
Valid 'toolsPaths.json' file found.
'toolsPaths.json' file updated!

        Enter path(s) to OpenOCD configuration file(s):
                Example: 'target/stm32f0x.cfg'. Absolute or relative to OpenOCD /scripts/ folder.
                If more than one file is needed, separate with comma.
                Paste here and press Enter: C:\Users\omis2\AppData\Roaming\GNUMCUEclipse\GNU MCU Eclipse\OpenOCD\0.10.0-12-20190422-2015\scripts\target\stm32l4x.cfg

        Enter path or command for 'stm32SvdPath':
        Paste here and press Enter: C:\Users\omis2\AppData\Roaming\GNUMCUEclipse\Keil.STM32L4xx_DFP.2.2.0\CMSIS\SVD\STM32L4x6.svd

ERROR (55 seconds).
Unexpected error occured during 'Update' procedure. Exception:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\Development\STM32\cubemxprojects\476EncTest\ideScripts\update.py", line 56, in <module>
    makefileData = makefile.getMakefileData(makeExePath, gccExePath)
  File "D:\Development\STM32\cubemxprojects\476EncTest\ideScripts\updateMakefile.py", line 93, in getMakefileData
    projectName = self.getMakefileVariable(makeExePath, gccExePath, self.mkfStr.projectName)[0]
  File "   D:\Development\STM32\cubemxprojects\476EncTest\ideScripts\updateMakefile.py", line 366, in getMakefileVariable
    proc = Popen(arguments, stdout=PIPE)
    File "C:\Users\omis2\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38- 32\lib\subprocess.py", line 854, in __init__
    self._execute_child(args, executable, preexec_fn, close_fds,
    File "C:\Users\omis2\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-   32\lib\subprocess.py", line 1307, in _execute_child
    hp, ht, pid, tid = _winapi.CreateProcess(executable, args,
    PermissionError: [WinError 5] Access is denied
```

Thanks for any help

Comment: I afraid you need to ask the authors of the script. How to use third party software questions or why third party software does not work are off-topic here

Comment: Thank you. As I look around here I have found similar instances of the problem I presented while running python on windows hence my inquiry. In many of those, the issue seemed more related to the environment than the script and was hoping my case would be similar. I have little experience with all this and have trouble understanding the Windows mechanisms possibly involved. Thanks for your response.